# Sorting Fields and Values in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need a little help with macro that can sort the data in the below pivot table.

I have a macro that copies Excel ranges from a few spreadsheets, then pastes the data into destination workbooks and updates multiple pivot tables.

Each time when I change a filter to the new month in the below pivot table, everything is sorted in the alphabetical order. As I need to change a filter on a monthly basis, I would like to ensure that the data is in the required order in this specific pivot table.

I would like to sort the pivot table by values in descending order but always only in the 4th column (for the last month - in this case for October). It needs to be done for both - countries and cities.

**Original Pivot Table:**

[image: Original Pivot Table]

**Required order of the pivot table:**

[image: Required order of the pivot table]

I tried to record the macro but no success.

Comment: *"I tried to record the macro but no success."* This is very meaningless. What did you record? Show the code you tried. Why *exactly* didn't that work? What did it do instead of what you expected?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Pᴇʜ and editing my post. I'm quite new to this forum so thanks also for your advises.

Regarding the above query; it seems that I recorded the macro moved and my pivot table into new tab thereafter. That's why it didn't work

The good news is, I finally managed to get this working.

Comment: Please don't use comment for code. If it belongs to your question [edit] the question and add it there. If it is a solution, post it as an answer and mark your own post as solution (may need to wait some time until you can vote your post).

Comment: Thanks Pᴇʜ. I will be able to mark this as a solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("COUNTRY").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Amount", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
    PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), 1

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("CITY").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Amount", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
    PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(3), 1
```

Thanks for your help in this matter Pᴇʜ